# Armadillo C++ Matrix Library - simplest way to initialize all values in a matrix to 999?

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

I'm very new to Armadillo but after searching around I can't find any answer to this. I need a matrix with all values initialized to a number like 999. Do I have to iterate through the whole thing and set them manually? Feel like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#fill) classes *Mat, Col, Row, Cube* have method **fill**.

Example:

```
mat A(5,5);
A.fill(999.0);
```